# Is there a way to git grep stdin?

Tags: git, grep, stdin

I want to use `git grep` with input taken from stdin. There is an option `--no-index` but according to [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt---no-index) it only allows to grep files in the current directory:

> --no-index
>
> Search files in the current directory that is not managed by Git.

I want to use `git grep` because it has an [option `--function-context`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--W) while ordinary grep does not have it. Is there a way to do it with `git grep`?

Comment: Nope, not possible directly. `git grep` was designed to grep through blobs in a commit. The solution to you problem, perhaps, is to `cat` stdin to a temporary file, run `git grep --no-index --function-context` with the file and then remove the file.